# Deriving Gradients for a Vanilla LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've been banging my head on this for far too long. The following code should be easy to understand; can someone assist me in discovering what I've done wrong?

The code passes a numerical gradient check for sequence of length=1. The general logic is as follows: in the outer loop, loop through the costs with respect to which to compute gradients. In the inner loop, back-prop through time for that cost, `J_t`.

```
def compute_gradients(self, x, y):
    softmax_outputs, hidden_state, cache = self.feed_forward_method(x)
    self.parameters.reset_gradients_to_zero()
    time_steps = np.arange(len(x))

    for t in time_steps[::-1]:
        label = y[t]

        # derivative of loss function w.r.t. softmax predictions
        dJdP = softmax_outputs[t]
        dJdP[label] -= 1

        # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_hy
        self.parameters.W_hy.gradient += np.outer(dJdP, hidden_state[t])

        # derivative of loss function w.r.t. b_y
        self.parameters.b_y.gradient += dJdP

        # derivative of loss function w.r.t. hidden state
        dJdH = dJdP @ self.parameters.W_hy.value

        # initialize dJdH_parent
        dJdH_parent = dJdH

        # initialize dJdC_parent
        dJdC_parent = 0

        # back-propagate through time
        back_prop_through_time_steps = np.arange( max(0, t-self.backprop_through_time_steps), t+1)
        for t_ in back_prop_through_time_steps[::-1]:

            # build input vector
            input_vector = np.arange(self.vocabulary_size) == x[t_]

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. o_t
            dJdO = dJdH_parent * np.tanh(cache['memory_cell'][t_])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. memory_cell
            dJdC = dJdC_parent + ( dJdH_parent * cache['output_gate'][t] * self._derivative_of_tanh(cache['memory_cell'][t]) )

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. Z_{o_t}
            dJdZ_o = dJdO * self._derivative_of_sigmoid(cache['output_gate'][t_])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. Z_{candidate_c_t}
            dJdZ_candidate_c = dJdC * cache['input_gate'][t_] * self._derivative_of_tanh(cache['candidate_memory_cell'][t_])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. Z_{i_t}
            dJdZ_i = dJdC * cache['candidate_memory_cell'][t_] * self._derivative_of_sigmoid(cache['input_gate'][t_])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. Z_{f_t}
            dJdZ_f = dJdC * cache['memory_cell'][t_-1] * self._derivative_of_sigmoid(cache['forget_gate'][t_])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_oh
            self.parameters.W_oh.gradient += np.outer(dJdZ_o, hidden_state[t_-1])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_ox
            self.parameters.W_ox.gradient += np.outer(dJdZ_o, input_vector)

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. b_o
            self.parameters.b_o.gradient += dJdZ_o

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_ch
            self.parameters.W_ch.gradient += np.outer(dJdZ_candidate_c, hidden_state[t_-1])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_cx
            self.parameters.W_cx.gradient += np.outer(dJdZ_candidate_c, input_vector)

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. b_c
            self.parameters.b_c.gradient += dJdZ_candidate_c

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_ih
            self.parameters.W_ih.gradient += np.outer(dJdZ_i, hidden_state[t_-1])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_ix
            self.parameters.W_ix.gradient += np.outer(dJdZ_i, input_vector)

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. b_i
            self.parameters.b_i.gradient += dJdZ_i

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_fh
            self.parameters.W_fh.gradient += np.outer(dJdZ_f, hidden_state[t_-1])

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. W_fx
            self.parameters.W_fx.gradient += np.outer(dJdZ_f, input_vector)

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. b_f
            self.parameters.b_f.gradient += dJdZ_f

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t *previous* hidden-state, via o_t
            dJdH_parent_o_t = dJdZ_o @ self.parameters.W_oh.value

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t *previous* hidden-state, via candidate_c_t
            dJdH_parent_candidate_c_t = dJdZ_candidate_c @ self.parameters.W_ch.value

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. *previous* hidden-state, via i_t
            dJdH_parent_i_t = dJdZ_i @ self.parameters.W_ih.value

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. *previous* hidden-state, via f_t
            dJdH_parent_f_t = dJdZ_f @ self.parameters.W_fh.value

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. *previous* hidden-state
            dJdH_parent = dJdH_parent_o_t + dJdH_parent_candidate_c_t + dJdH_parent_i_t + dJdH_parent_f_t

            # derivative of loss function w.r.t. *previous* memory cell, via current memory cell
            dJdC_parent = dJdC * cache['forget_gate'][t_]

    return self.parameters
```